# Failed to communicate with VM agent on Ubuntu machine even though it's running

Tags: azure

I have setup a backup job and just noticed that for the last 4 days I've not have backups.  When I look at the error details I get this:

```
Could not communicate with the VM agent for snapshot status. Snapshot VM sub task timed out.
```

When I login to the Ubuntu (14.04) machine and look at the processes I can see that waagent is running.

```
13174 root       20   0  263M 18100  5736 S  0.0  0.3  0:02.23 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/waagent -daemon
20953 root       20   0  263M 18100  5736 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.12 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/waagent -daemon
13154 root       20   0  263M 18100  5736 S  0.0  0.3  0:25.98 /usr/bin/python /usr/sbin/waagent -daemon
```

What can be wrong?  I had this same problem about a month ago as well and I believe rebooting fixed it, but this is definitely not a permanent solution.